Calculate alternator power from open voltage and short current
A 3-phase BLDC motor, used as an alternator, outputs 3V open-circuit and 5A short-circuit at a given RPM. How can you calculate or at least estimate its useful power at that RPM if we connect it to a matched load? What is the theoretical speed-to-power law of such alternators, e.g. twice the speed - how much the power?

About all you can say simplistically is that the maximum output power will be approximately when the voltage is half and the current is half i.e. 1.5 volts × 2.5 amps = 3.75 watts.
The above assumes the generator behaves like a voltage source with an output impedance that is resistive. It will be a tad more complex than this but, if you want a quick and simple answer, that's a reasonable estimate.
